# Fiware Orion Bug (empty contextAttributeVector for ContextElementResponse 1) Error

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

We have an IoT platform environment on AWS EKS that uses a fiware stack comprising iotagent, Orion (version 3.4.0), and Draco.

Our objective is to conduct scalability testing for 420 devices. For every 30 seconds, a command request is sent from a device simulator to the spring boot application API(running on EKS), this in turn calls ORION and updates the payload in Mongodb of ORION.

the payload will send a Batch update Orion call (POST http://orion:1026/v2/op/update), using fiware-service and fiware-servicepath with payload.

Please find the payload information below.

```
curl -iX POST \
  'http://orion:1026/v2/op/update' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: building' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /co/pf/building' \
  -d '{"actionType":"update",
  "entities":[{"wifi":{"type":"command","value":{"requestTime":"2023-11-23T18:50:00.060",
  "payload":{"wifi-heater_7_status":"on","requestTimestamp":"2023-11-23T18:49:59.091",
  "wifi-heater_8_status":"on"},
  "transactionId":"fbxxx679-87a5-4xxx-83fb-049xxxxxc7df"}},
  "id":"urn:ngsi-ld:Equipment:wifi001",
  "type":"Equipment"}]}
```

We are facing this error in the spring boot application REST API call response from Orion log , we see below message response:

```
fiware-orion   | "time=2023-11-22T05:14:54.019Z | lvl=ERROR | 
corr=11234246-88f6-12e342-a5ca-e66xwsssxc | trans=170000003-387-00000000001 | 
from=99.999.99.99 | srv=building | subsrv=/co/pf/building| 
comp=Orion | op=postUpdateContext.cpp[684]:postUpdateContext | 
msg=Orion Bug (empty contextAttributeVector for ContextElementResponse 1)",
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before? If so, could you please share the solution that worked for you?

I am grateful for your assistance!

Comment: Do you have some registration covering the entity you are updating (urn:ngsi-ld:Equipment:wifi001)? Could you edit your question post to include the request (curl) used to create that registration?

Comment: Thank you @fgalan, It is just example payload. I am getting **Orion Bug (empty contextAttributeVector for ContextElementResponse 1)** this error. Can you please assist me ?

Answer (score 0):

The trace you are getting is probably a false positive in error log tracing, fixed in [PR #4132](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/pull/4132), included in [Orion 3.7.0](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/releases/tag/3.7.0)

> Fix: wrong log traces in update forwarding cases

I'd recommend you to upgrade to newest Orion version (at the moment of writing this, it is Orion 3.10.1 but it can be even newer in the moment you read this :) and test again.

Comment: Thank you @fgalan, I will upgrade to newest Orion version I will let you know the result.